# Jupyter Notebook Unable to Configure and Install Library

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, configure, make-install

I am trying to install exafmm to use in Python 3.8 using Jupyter notebook.

It should be simple, and so I don't know what the problem is.  I've been stuck and unable to solve this.
When I run the code, I get the error

```
File "<ipython-input-8-d0f090c60924>", line 3
    ./configure
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
    !git clone https://github.com/exafmm/exafmm-t.git
    %cd exafmm-t
    ./configure
    make
    make install
```

I have tried putting `sudo` in front of `./configure`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you are planning to use this library with `python` and `jupyter notebook`, I guess you should not build this library from the source code. As per their documentation, `this approach is only necessary for the users who want to use exafmm-t in C++ applications` (reference: https://exafmm.github.io/exafmm-t/compile.html#install-exafmm-t)

Try running the following bash command in your `notebook` (reference https://exafmm.github.io/exafmm-t/compile.html#install-exafmm-t-s-python-package):

```sh
! pip install git+https://github.com/exafmm/exafmm-t.git
```